# AWS VPC Re-IP (change the IP address)

Tags: amazon-web-services

Here's my question ... There is a scenario to change the ip address(CONFLICTS with my client ip address) in the AWS vpc subnet.

Through AWS Direct connect , we setup connectivity between aws vpc and client data center.
IP conflict to particular ip ranges. So have to completely release that particular ip ranges and have to assign new ip ranges for achieving this requires the dependicies also get to change. Requesting all your input on how we can achieve this in dependicies terms like route table, NACL,RDS Database etc....
 How can we achieve this. please let me know the dependicies available to change the ip address in the VPC subnets .Please input your ideas and steps to achieve this scenario.

Client asking us to completely release that particular subnet ip ranges in the VPC.
I have only primary ip address only to all the aws instance.

My exact need is to change the IP address what are the steps required to change and dependicies available in the backend to change the ip adress in aws vpc.

Comment: Hi ! Please elaborate: which plateform are you using, how are you configuring AWS, what is your exact need, why would you want a such thing... Also try to edit your post to improve its readibility: the more readable it is, the more people will be likely to help you !

Comment: I have given my exact need. please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Once a VPC has been created you cannot change the addresses.

You must delete and create a new VPC.

[How do I modify the IP address range of my Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) or VPC subnet?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/vpc-ip-address-range/)

[EDIT]

Amazon now allows you to add CIDR blocks to an existing VPC. These additional CIDR blocks can be deleted, but the original CIDR block cannot be deleted or modified.

[Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) now allows customers to expand their existing VPCs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/08/amazon-virtual-private-cloud-vpc-now-allows-customers-to-expand-their-existing-vpcs/)